# Firestore rules limit: max file size of 64KB reached for firestore.rules file. Now what?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I recently reached this limit. The error that the cli gives is very unobvious simply stating `Request contains an invalid argument` and it took me quite a while to realize I had reached the maximum limit of 64KB for the `firestore.rules` file. Would be great if that error was a bit more obvious as it would have saved me a bunch of time.

The limits are documented here.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#security_rule_limits

After doing a bunch of searching around solutions to the 64KB limit and not finding anything I contacted support. Their guidance was somewhat helpful but in other cases a bit shocking.

I'm adding these details here for anyone else that is struggling with this issue as not much else comes up when searching on Google.

Here was their response

```
The given limit on the ruleset size is fixed, and it cannot be increased. However, we do offer ways to reduce the size of your ruleset, or 'lines of code' in particular. 

Here are some suggestions:
1) You can define your custom functions, which can be reusable throughout the ruleset
- This will definitely save you a lot of data space, and makes it look organized, as overused conditions can be called in one place

2) If possible, reconsider the database structure by making it efficient
- This means the less the number of collections and subcollections, the less rules are written, which makes the ruleset smaller in size
- Refactor your database structure and security rules as much as possible by removing unnecessary or redundant parts

3) Minimize the use of data validation rules, and put it on application-level instead
- Not only it can reduce lines of code, but it can reduce the number of expressions evaluated to avoid reaching the given limit of 1000 expressions per request
- As much as possible, use your app logic to ensure your data is on the right character length, correct data type, meets the patter criteria, etc. You may also use your app's advanced UI elements like a password textbox, a textbox that you can limit the character length, among others
```

Some of these suggestions such as using functions are definitely helpful. However, i'm a bit surprised by the suggestions to restructure my database and to put validation on the application level.

- In my case i've already used functions quite a lot in my database rules and have removed most of the redundancy.
- Asking me to reconsider the database structure and having to overhaul my application for the sake of reducing my rules file size is a huge ask for little gain.
- Minimize the use of data validation rules seems completely against the design of the Firestore database. The database is designed in such a way that you can directly connect your client to your database which removes the middle application logic. Suggesting to do this seems to go directly against the architectural nature of Firebase. I would prefer to keep building my application in this way (and want to maintain my security), so this seems like a non-option.

Does anyone else have any suggestions on how to handle this issue?

Comment: The max file size is now 256KB (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#security_rule_limits). The change is as of June 2020: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/06/new-firestore-security-rules-features.html

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this problem does not seem too dissimilar from trying to keep javascript file size down on the web. A lot of the same approaches taken by javascript minifiers could be used to reduce the size of the firebase rules file. It would be great if Firebase provided a tool like this for us.

Out of desperation I made a simple minifier that removes whitespace and comments. In case anyone else finds themselves in a similar situation and needs a quick fix. https://github.com/brianneisler/firemin